# Add a number to a SQL Server table that increments on a condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table that looks like this ( ID is a PK identity field )

```
  ID Date                  Condition     Call_Count    
  1  2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     0    
  2  2015-03-02 14:05:10   Transferred    0    
  3  2015-03-02 14:06:02   Transferred    0    
  4  2015-03-02 14:07:00   Transferred    0    
  5  2015-03-02 14:07:50   Terminated     0    
  6  2015-03-02 14:07:60   Transferred    0    
  7  2015-03-02 14:08:55   Terminated     0    
  8  2015-03-02 14:08:56   Terminated     0
```

I have tried the below:

```
DECLARE @LoopId INT = 1, 
    @Call_Count INT = 1, 
    @callend INT,
    @maxId INT,
    @LoopCounter INT

Select @MaxId = max(ID) from Table1     

WHILE(@LoopId <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @callend = charindex('Terminated', Reason)
     from Table1 where ID = @LoopId

   set @Call_Count = @Call_Count + case when @callend > 0 then 1 else 0 end

   IF @LoopId > 1 
   begin
     update Table1
        set Call_Counter = @Call_Count
      WHERE Id = @LoopID
   end

   SET @LoopId  = @LoopId  + 1        
END
```

The result I got was this:

```
  ID Date                  Condition     Call_Count    
  1   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     1  
  2   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     2
  3   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     3
  4   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     4  
  5   2015-03-02 14:05:10   Transferred    4    
  6   2015-03-02 14:06:02   Transferred    4    
  7   2015-03-02 14:07:00   Transferred    4    
  8   2015-03-02 14:07:50   Terminated     5    
  9   2015-03-02 14:07:60   Transferred    5    
  10  2015-03-02 14:08:55   Terminated     6    
  11  2015-03-02 14:08:56   Terminated     6
```

I need to get an ID field generated that will have this result, it needs to change the number after the last "Terminated" as to put one "call" in a group.

```
  ID Date                  Condition     Call_Count    
  1   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     1  
  2   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     2
  3   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     3
  4   2015-03-02 14:05:05   Terminated     4  
  5   2015-03-02 14:05:10   Transferred    5    
  6   2015-03-02 14:06:02   Transferred    5    
  7   2015-03-02 14:07:00   Transferred    5    
  8   2015-03-02 14:07:50   Terminated     5    
  9   2015-03-02 14:07:60   Transferred    6    
  10  2015-03-02 14:08:55   Terminated     6    
  11  2015-03-02 14:08:56   Terminated     7
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: I forgot to add, this is SQL Server 2012, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution that should work on any version of sql server is using an update with <strike>an inner join to a correlated derived table</strike>
a correlated sub query.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions - If you would have done that yourself, I would have posted a correct and tested solution in the first attampt)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    [Date] datetime,
    Condition nvarchar(20),
    Call_Counter int
)
INSERT INTO Table1 ([Date], Condition) VALUES 
('2015-03-02 14:05:05', 'Terminated'),
('2015-03-02 14:05:10', 'Transferred'),
('2015-03-02 14:06:02', 'Transferred'),
('2015-03-02 14:07:00', 'Transferred'),
('2015-03-02 14:07:50', 'Terminated'),
('2015-03-02 14:07:59', 'Transferred'),
('2015-03-02 14:08:55', 'Terminated'),
('2015-03-02 14:08:56', 'Terminated')
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Call_Counter = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) As CallCounter
        FROM Table1 t2
        WHERE Condition = 'Terminated'
        AND t2.ID <= t1.ID
    ) 
FROM Table1 t1
```

[See live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/IMV54807)

first attempt (wrong)

```
UPDATE t1
SET Call_Counter = CallCounter
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) As CallCounter
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE Condition = 'Terminated'
    AND ID <= t1.ID
) t3
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar, I'll give it a try. I am getting some syntax errors but I get the drift of what you explain.

Comment: Mmm ok I ran the query against my normal query. The result looked like my first attempt, so it changes the number on the first "Terminated", whereas it should end the call_counter at "Terminated" and then start the next number. So the call shows it's terminated and then transferred, where it should show it's transferred and the last record begin terminated. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution so Zohar. But I rather calculate all the values first. Also take advantage of window functions.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FNNQ33928)**

```
WITH CTE as (
    SELECT ID , 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN [Condition] = 'Terminated' THEN 1 END) 
           OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) as rn
    FROM Table1
)      
UPDATE A
SET [Call_Count] =  CASE WHEN [Condition] = 'Terminated' 
                         THEN B.rn
                         ELSE B.rn + 1
                    END
FROM Table1 A
JOIN CTE B
  ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for the help. I still have the original problem where the count changes on "Terminated", it should change on the next row. So to measure the time a call was done, it should not start with Terminated but with the row after that and the last row in the batch should be the Terminated... Not sure if I explain it correctly.

Comment: Can you modify the rextester demo with some data so I can see the problem? Update the data ... send me the link .. tell me what result you expect and I will compare with the result of my query to fix it.